# Is it feasible to develop a chat app using php sockets?

Tags: php, sockets, chat, p2p

I'm looking to develop a chat application using php sockets, I'm not looking to include database as a bridge between nodes, reason being the amount of database interaction will ultimately be an overhead..

Pls suggest..

Comment: I have tried to build it in php but handling socket was bit messy for me ,
So I moved to socket.io which is far good library for long term socket programing. BTW it is nodejs library

Answer (score 1):

First link in google.
http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash8/php5sockets_flash8.htm

Remove flash part, and you'll have what you need.

Comment: I'll see to it, the question still remains, is it feasible? should this actually be done using sockets, wherein I can use database to do it? I'm also trying to implement file transfer to it, maybe using the p2p paradigm...what do you reckon?

Comment: It is possible. But it would be better to do it using ajax technology.
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/php-ajax-chat-application-mia-chat/

You want to do p2p file transfer for a web application?

Comment: yeah, the concept is not pure p2p, but an involvement of server for processing php would be a prerequisite, its something that can be done if thought of, imagine involving the server for just figuring out the nodes available for communication...how about it?

Comment: This is already centralized control. This is feasible. But I don't know if it can be done using PHP.
Okay, server will have table of online nodes. He is a router. But how are you going to transfer data?

Comment: well i've worked with Java on sockets, as far as Java is concerned I used pipelines, I hope its possible in php too..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hocking up to a message queue?

http://www.rabbitmq.com/ for example